# Readline in buffer reader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I've used readline() method to read first line of my buffer reader
then,after checking something in the first line, I want to send my buffer reader into function, without loosing the first line,
As I understood, the readline() method, seek the first line of buffer reader,
how should I reverse it?

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(serverinput);
String onelineofinput = bufferedReader.readLine();
if(onelineofinput...)
...
  then
  sendpackets(IPaddress, port, bufferedReader, connection);
  //bufferedreader should send completely here.
```

Comment: not quite a duplicate since the OP does not specifically ask about mark() and reset().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `java.io.PushbackReader` between the `BufferedReader` and the input.

After you have examined the first line you push it back to the `PushbackReader` (and also the line break which is swallowed by the `BufferedReader`) and then pass the `PushbackReader` to `sendpackets`.

```
PushbackReader pbreader = new PushbackReader (serverinput);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(pbreader);
String onelineofinput = bufferedReader.readLine();
if (onelineofinput...) {
    pbreader.unread(onelineofinput.toCharArray());
    pbreader.unread('\n');
    sendpackets(IPaddress, port, new BufferedReader(pbreader), connection);
}
```

Comment: but i want to send bufferreader to my method .. @wero

Comment: @user122434 then put it into in a new BufferedReader, see my edit.

Comment: thanks, but why do you think that mark and reset is not good to use here?@wero

Comment: @user122434 it is a viable solution if you can guarantee that the first line length is smaller than the buffer size of the BufferedReader. If you know that than go for it.

Comment: ok, thank you very much:)